# Eight fair coins are flipped. Find the probability that 5 heads and 3 tails are obtained

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations, combinations

I am struggling to solve this probability question. I don't know which approach to take with regards to finding the equation for calculating the given amount.

$${8\choose5}\left(\frac12\right)^1\left(\frac12\right)^2\cdots$$

What should I do to find a generic approach to problems with this format. I have another that is similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to find the probability $P(k)$ of having $k$ successes 
$$P(k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Where  $n$ is number of independent experiments, $k$ is number of successes and $n-k$ is number of  failures.

In this case: $n=8, k=5,n-k=3$  (without loss of generality I chose head is success). $p$ is the probability of having a success, in this case it is equal to $0.5$.

Comment: Thanks I will try to solve it now.

Comment: Did you manage to solve It?